# What could explain why “request desktop site” option is greyed out on some pages on Chrome on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-chrome

I see that on some pages (eg, some page on wise.com), the “request desktop site” option is greyed out. What could be the reason?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 2):

> What could explain why “request desktop site” option is greyed out on some pages on Chrome on my iPhone?

Because, the site developers didn't see the need for or didn't want to implement a view port configuration that worked with desktop browsers; it’s a design choice.    There's no (web development) rule that mandates a browser must support all viewport configurations - mobile and desktop.

If the "Desktop Site" option id greyed out that means there's no native desktop browser support.  This is not related to Apple or Apple products;  it's standard across all devices and platforms.